# Paint bicycle keeping stickers

Tags: used-bike, customization, paint

I  have seen a used bicycle for me to buy, which has got me mainly interested, but I don't like the fact it is white. Is it possible to paint it another color keeping the stickers?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Aside - note there's a difference between Stickers and Decals, which bay also be known as water transfers.  Heat may soften a sticker's adhesive but won't do anything for a decal.

Answer (score 4):

To repaint metal, you'll have to strip the current coating. This means you'll have to remove the stickers as well. It is unreasonable to attempt to reuse them, just as it would be silly (or at least ungodly expensive) to try to move a printed image from one T-shirt to another.

You can, however, buy and apply new stickers, if you can find the ones you like. For Rockshox forks they are readily available in several colors. I can also see that stickers for Cube frames are also available.

You can also go with e.g. vinyl wrap applied to existing frame. It can be made to your custom design, for a price.

P.S. My rough estimations are that any sort of repainting of a used frameset is likely to cost at least as much as the bicycle itself. The paint itself may be cheap, but working time to strip the frame and to repaint it are not. Unless you have enough free time to do it yourself, are not afraid to make mistakes and have an empty ventilated garage for a week (it takes several days for several coats of paint to dry).

Answer (score 3):

It would be practically impossible to paint the white part of the frame and fork without painting over the blue decals (stickers)

Bikes (and cars) have a primer coat, color coat and clear coat of paint. The clear coat is well, clear and protects the color. The decals are sometimes under the clear coat and sometimes on top.

To get paint to stick to the bike you would at least have to sand down the clear coat to get the paint to stick to it, you'd have to do that around the decals, then tape up the decals to paint around them. That would take lots of time and add significant cost to the bike.

An alternative is to strip the decals off, sand, respray, have replacement decals printed and apply them, but again that would take lots of time and add significant cost.

If you don't like the color of this bike it would be far easier and cost effective to just find a bike in a color you do like.

Answer (score 0):

complete nuisance!!!. You can paint whatever you want with what you want - but,  a bit patience is needed, and elbow grease :)
In this case - the easiest and cheapest option is to use a decal on top of the paint - ( quality stickers with warm hairdryer :)There are several companies selling bike frame decals - $15-$50. Find yours, sand down your frame (wet and dry paper, 220/400 ) - keep checking the difference between the paint and the decals - make sure they are even (but don't worry too much) when is done - mask up whatever you need -  and take to your local spraying shop.